# Ripped off display connector, raspberry not working anymore?

Tags: pi-3, sd-card, display

i am using a Raspi 3b v1.2.

I ripped parts of my display connector off by accident and then removed the whole thing with pliers, because i will never use it anyways. Now my raspberry won't boot. Is a connection between the pins of the display connector necessary for the microSD reader to work?

I know what i did was dumb, so please no further shaming. I'm mad enough about myself already.

Comment: You probably damaged one or more traces when you ripped off the connector. Very unlikely that it's repairable. Get a new one.

Comment: That'll be hard to answer without further details, i.e. pictures. It is very well possible, that some traces of the removed connector on the circuit board are shorted now... and should be removed more thouroughly.

Comment: @Dirk yeah i think that's the case. Welp. Time to order a new one :(

Comment: Just bending a PCB without any visible damage can be enough to kill it.

Answer (score 3):

Time to buy a new Pi. Who knows what damage you have caused to the board.